# VBS Script that shows the files created on a specific date

Tags: date, vbscript

I want to create a script that shows the files created on a specific date in a specific location.
As for now I created this:

```html
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "!\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from CIM_DataFile where Drive='C:' AND Path='\\' AND CreationDate Like '20071107%' ")
For Each objFile in colFiles
Buffer = Buffer & objFile.FileName & " - " & objFile.CreationDate & vbNewLine 
Next
Wscript.echo Buffer
```

But I am getting error in this line: " AND CreationDate Like '20071107%' "
So it does not work in such a way as I thought it will be - in C:\ I have a lot eula.txt files created on 2007 11 07.
I do not ask about finished code, but only for a clue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause of a `WQL` query defends or inhibits from using wildcards in [`CIM_DATETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx) values. Use [SWbemDateTime object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393687(v=vs.85).aspx) as follows:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim objWMIService, colFiles, objFile, dTargetDate, dMinDate, dMaxDate, dateTime

Set dateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
dTargetDate = #2007-11-07#          ' date literal in yyyy-mm-dd format

dateTime.SetVarDate( dTargetDate)   ' convert to CIM_DATETIME
dMinDate = datetime               

dateTime.SetVarDate( DateAdd( "d", 1, dTargetDate))
dMaxDate = datetime
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & dMaxDate


Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "!\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery ( _
  "Select * from CIM_DataFile where Drive='c:' AND Path='\\'" _
    & " AND CreationDate >= '" & dMinDate & "'" _
    & " AND CreationDate  < '" & dMaxDate & "'" _
    )

If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
  strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & "no files found"
Else
  For Each objFile in colFiles
    strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & objFile.FileName  & " " & objFile.Extension  _
      & " - " & objFile.CreationDate
  Next
End If

Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit
```